# mobile joomla and jquery ui conflict

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, joomla

We have a mobile version of our Joomla site using mobile Joomla and everything was working fine until we introduced the jquery UI for the autocompletion functionality into the equation. We now get the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'match'" which after googling seems to indicate it being a conflict between Mobile Joomla and jQuery UI.

We can prove this if we remove the UI it runs fine again.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: have you tried using a jQuery auto complete plugin rather than jQueryUI?

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, I will take a look for a plugin as a few people have said UI can cause conflicts. Any suggestions on a good plug-in.

Cheers, Richard

Comment: May I suggest you have a look at this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete

Comment: Hi, the autocomplete at bassistance has been deprecated. Are there any other basic ones you could recommend.
Cheers

Comment: Hi Lodde
Took your advice and found another plugin - which works a treat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.noConflict();` and inside `(document).ready(function()` put `$` inside `(function()`

**Example:**

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi akobaindreas11,

Thanks for the reply. We used jQuery.noconflict() and then used jQuery in-place of $ and it worked a treat.

Cheers Rich